# MVC 5.0 500 - Internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an MVC 5 website using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows Server 2016 Machine.

I build and run the application from VS and it works great.

I published it locally, pointed IIS to the root folder.
The Application Pool is set to .Net CLR Version v4.0.30319.

When I try to access the page on the web, I get a generic error 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

There is nothing in the IIS logs.

Not sure how to get this error so I can see it...or if it is a more basic issue.  Any ideas on the best way to proceed?

Comment: Did you look at the Windows Event Logs? Did you try adding logging directly to your application?

Comment: Yes....I added Logging, but got nothing.  Also, nothing in the event log...I am suspecting a more basic setup issue...brand new machine.  Also, The logging I added was custom written...is there a more basic option?

Comment: Did you use any of the .Net Core stuff?  Visual Studio uses IIS Express not IIS, what are the binding?  Does the AppPool have access to the folder?  Need more information.

Comment: No....visual Studio 2015...I think core is 2017?

Comment: @ER.Cons You can use some of Core in 2015, it was in beta for it.

Comment: I am not familiar with Core as of yet...what can I use to solve this?  Is there anything useful?

Comment: Did you use any of the .Net Core stuff? Visual Studio uses IIS Express not IIS, what are the binding? Does the AppPool have access to the folder? Need more information      IIS_Iusr has read and execute.  The binding is the host name and IP...am I missing something?  I believe the App Pool has access...how do I make sure?

Comment: OK...I added the Default App Pool and gave it full permissions on the root folder....No Change.....any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

To configure within Microsoft Server 2016, do the following:

- Make sure you've installed the feature set for Web Server & Hosting are installed.
- If those are installed, create a directory such as: "C:\Program Files\Sample"
- Publish your application to the directory
- Open Internet Information System
- Disable Default Site
- Create a New Site
- Create a Site Name "Sample" (Take note of the Application Pool Name)
- Now link "C:\Program Files\Sample" in Physical Path
- For now leave the binding defaulted, this will trigger wildcard
- Uncheck Start Website Immediately
- Navigate back to "C:\Program Files\Sample" (Accessible through IIS also)
- Right-Click and go to Permissions
- Choose add new user
- Type in "IIS AppPool\Sample"
- Choose access your application will require.
- Apply those changes, then navigate and start your web-site.

If that doesn't work, you can check the following:

---

**Application Pool:**

- Sample should of defaulted to integrated and 4.0, if not change it. If your utilizing .Net Core application, you want it to be **Unmanaged Code**

**Programs and Features:**

- Make sure that you have .Net 3.5, 3.0, 2.0 enabled.
- Hostable Web Core & Internet Information System (Under Web Server) for you.
- World Wide Web Services Enabled, with the proper Application Development Features.

[image]

[image]

**Dependencies:**

- You may have to install https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53840
- If you have Core, you'll need: https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting

Comment: This really helped...got me further down the path.     I now have this error: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.    Which seems much easier.  I thought I had all the permissions I needed...and have IIS pointing to the root, where the web.config is.  Any other ideas....?

Comment: I believe I found the permission issue, however, now I am displaying the directory information instead of the page itself.  I would assume that my advanced settings in IIS is pointing to the wrong place.  My understanding is that I point that to the folder where the web.config is located....which is the root.  What am I missing?

Comment: You should make sure that your `AppPool` has the proper permissions to the directory and supports pass through.  Also, check IIS and make sure that inside IIS you allow anonymous.

Comment: @ER.Cons That would be correct, but if your Site supports Virtual Applications, rather than being a root site it could do that.